# Как принудить пользователя использовать созданную мною лицензию в MIT лицензии

Tags: лицензирование, библиотека

У меня есть своя библиотека/фреймворк, я использую MIT лицензию. Как я могу заставить того, кто использует мою библиотеку при выкладывании его проекта, впесто его лицензии указать лицензию моей библиотеки?

Comment: Тогда это будет уже не MIT

Comment: При выкладивании проекта куда? В открытый доступ или для пользования?

Comment: Для пользования

Comment: Вы имеете в виду исходные тексты или конечный бинарный код?

Comment: Для пользования - никак. Захочу - сотру все лицензии и всё. Никто никогда не узнает где и что я взял.